# Fatal error: Call to undefined function. Underscore me

Tags: functions, fatal-error

After searching and readding on diferent questions about this topic. Still didn't find a solution.

I am working in a local server. In wampserver. My wordpress folders are inside a myfolder. Inside wp-content and in themes I have my theme template.

Looks like this:

wamp/www/myfolder/wp-content/themes/mytheme

In the other themes I am getting the same call. And itsn't just the function get_header. Other functions are also undefined. So, it seems the problem comes calling to wordpress functions.

Have reinstaled Wordpress and still having the same problemo.

I have all wordpress folders. I am sure it has to be something wrong from the themes to wordpress folders. But it looks everything fine.

In other way, from wampserver/localhost/mypage I can see the website. But, in my editor (phpstorm) i get all the functions with another color telling me that they are undefined. The browser links from editor brings me to this "Fatal call function undefined..."

I am using Underscore me template. Maybe am I doing something wrong with Underscore?

or maybe it´s just a settings problem with phpstorm? In this case would not be a Wordpress issue I guess...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you have defined the index.php file and any other required files?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: So what you're saying is if you view it in the Browser the site is fine, but PHPStorm is reporting that functions are undefined?

Comment: Yess. From localhost/mypage It works. But, if I try to open It from the phpstorm links to the browsers I get the "Fatal call... " And in all the editor it's telling me that functions are undefined.Maybe,  the editor doesn't recognize them?